# Understanding `purrr::pmap` with a dataframe inside `mutate` in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I want to make the sum of the first 3 columns with `pmap`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(new = pmap(select(., 1:3), ~ sum(.))) # FAILS

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(new = pmap(., ~ sum(.[1:3]))) # FAILS

                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb new
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  NA
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  NA
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  NA
```

I know how to do it with `rowwise` or `RowSums` but I want a solution with `pmap`.

Comment: In your code `sum(.)` is equal to `sum(..1)`. It only uses the first variable but if you would like to sum all 3 in your code you could modify it as `mtcars %>% 
    mutate(new = pmap(select(., 1:3), ~ sum(c(...))))`. Simply replacing `.` with `c(...)` would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `pmap` solution would be:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(new = pmap(., ~ sum(..1, ..2, ..3)))
```

Or, slightly better IMO:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(new = pmap(select(., 1:3), sum)) 

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(new = pmap(select(., 1:3), ~ sum(...)))
```

Or, event better, by combining with `across`:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(new = pmap(across(1:3), sum))
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does `mtcars %>% 
  mutate(new = pmap(select(., 1:3), ~ sum(.)))` fail?

Comment: I should'nt have taken `sum` as an example

Comment: Check Anoushivaran R's answer this is it

Answer (score 3):

> Why does mtcars %>% mutate(new = pmap(select(., 1:3), ~ sum(.))) fail?

In your code `sum(.)` is equal to `sum(..1)`. It only uses the first variable but if you would like to take all 3 in your function call you could modify it as:

```
mtcars %>% mutate(new = pmap(select(., 1:3), ~ sum(c(...))))
```

Simply replacing `.` with `c(...)` would do.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you want to have a `pmap` solution, but my favourite way of avoiding the very slow `rowwise` is a combination of `across` and `apply`:

```
mtcars |>
  mutate(new = apply(across(1:3), 1, sum))

                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   new
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 187.0
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 187.0
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 134.8
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 285.4
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 386.7
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 249.1
...
```

Comment: It seems to be the answer that most suits my problem, strangely

Comment: Well, it looks more or less the same as the last option in Maël's answer, but from my experience and depnding on the size of the task, the `apply` version is usually 10%-100% faster than `pmap`.